# Restarting program using os.system to save memory?

Tags: python, memory, while-loop, os.system

I'm using Python to scrape a website for specific links or keywords, and want to send a request about every 5 seconds. Initially I was using a `while True` loop to send my requests every 5 seconds, but with every loop my program used about 1mb of memory more than before. With me wanting to run my program on a Raspberry Pi for potentially multiple days, this would fill up the memory pretty quickly.

Instead of using the while True loop, once my program ran through all the code I use

```
os.system("python program.py")
```

to restart the program, meaning running through the code over and over won't gain any memory and stay at an average of about 38mb.

So my question is: Is there any downside of me doing this? Can any problems occur when I want my computer to run a new instance of a program every 5 seconds for days?

EDIT: added code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import time
import os
import psutil

while True:
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
    source = requests.get(url).text                                             
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')                                        
    for link in soup.find_all("a"):                                             
        print(link.get('href'))

    time.sleep(5)
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print(process.memory_info().rss)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: If the memory consumption is increasing, that means you probably have a memory leak. Instead of restarting the application, fix the memory leak problem.

Comment: If you are willing to restart your program and just trash any data you've accumulated then it suggests that you're persisting data on each loop that you don't need. Without seeing your code, it's not possible to understand why the memory footprint grows but clearly you don't intend it

Comment: This is a classic [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) in my opinion.

Comment: @zvone I added a code which is essentially what I'm doing, but even this simple code causes my memory to go up every loop. It started with 32mb and gains about 0.7mb every loop.

Comment: @roganjosh I added a code which is essentially what I'm doing, but even this simple code causes my memory to go up every loop. It started with 32mb and gains about 0.7mb every loop.

Comment: The code you added seems fine to me. Maybe you didn't run long enough until the garbage collector cleaned it up. Maybe is a bug in the underlying library. Which version of CPython, requests and BeautifulSoup are you using?

Comment: @PedroLacerda I'm using python 3.6.8, BeautifulSoup is bs4 version 0.0.1, and requests version 2.20.1

Comment: This seems to be a case of premature optimization. There is no memory leak. When I run this code without `time.sleep` (so memory consumption grows much much faster), it always stays at around 50 MB (as expected). It is normal that it sometimes goes up for various reasons, and it does, but then it comes down again. So everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest it sounds like the program should be re-written. If you are storing data internally which you don't need (which from the sounds of it you are), you need to ask yourself why you are. If you need that data, write it out and reset the variable.

Some more clarity would really help here - ie - the code itself so we could figure out the real problem.

Comment: I added a code which is essentially what I'm doing, but even this simple code causes my memory to go up every loop. It started with 32mb and gains about 0.7mb every loop.

Comment: Instagram does it. They has some server that runs until the memory consumption is to high, then they restart it.

They used a modified version of CPython with the garbage collector disabled to be honest. It wasn't a memory leak like the one in the question.